# Why HasMany Associate makes an UPDATE query

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have the following JavaScript code with `sequelize.js` and wonder why the `UPDATE` query happens.

ProductModel:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});

  Product.associate = function (models) {
    Product.hasMany(models['ProductPicture'], {
      foreignKey: 'product_id'
    });

    Product.hasMany(models['ProductFeature'], {
      foreignKey: 'product_id'
    })
  };

  return Product;
};
```

Code:

```js
Product.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 1
    }
}).then(product => {
    return product.addProductPictures([{
        picture: "/images/placeholder.png"
    }, {
        picture: "/images/placeholder2.png"
    }]);
}).then(pictures => {
    // console.log(pictures)
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Output:

```sh
Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `name`, `price`, `profit`, `category`, `brand`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Products` AS `Product` WHERE `Product`.`id` = 1;
Executing (default): UPDATE `product_features` SET `product_id`=? WHERE `id` IN ('[object Object]', '[object Object]')
```

So, why the `SELECT` query is followed by an `UPDATE` query?